# TopCoder algorithm: BrightLamps -- n lamp

Tags: algorithm

The problem is [here](http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=13343).

I have read others solution and ideas, but I don't understand them.

The following is **mnbvmar**'s idea, can you explain it in more detail and
do you think it is right?

> If you flip two consecutive K-element subsequences (that is, `(i, i + 1, ..., i + K - 1)` and `(i + 1, ..., i + K)`), only two lamps get toggled (`i` and `i + K`).
>
> Now it's crucial to note that every combination that is possible to do with `K`-element flips, can also be done with the following two:
>
> 1. toggle first `K` lamps,
> 2. toggle any two lamps distant by `K`.
>
> (each toggling of `K` consecutive lamps is a compound of these operations). It's much simpler now. Of course, each operation can be done zero times or once (it's no use doing it more than once).
>
> Let's say we haven't used first operation in optimal solution. Then our sequence dissolves into `K` sequences of elements distant by `K`, in which you can toggle two consecutive elements. This is easy to solve; if `i`-th sequence has an even number of turned off lamps, you can turn them all on; in opposite case it's obvious we can't turn them all on, but it's possible to leave off only the least valuable lamp in the sequence.
>
> What if we use the first operation? Then we just toggle first `K` lamps and then do exactly the same steps as before.

Comment: What is it that you don't understand here?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say we have 10 lamps A-J and `k=4`. Then we can flip any of the X-sequences below:

```
ABCDEFGHIJ  
XXXX         //flip starting at A, changes A,B,C,D
 XXXX        //flip starting at B, changes B,C,D,E
  XXXX       //...
   XXXX
    XXXX
     XXXX
```

.

If we execute the flip sequence starting at lamp "S" and right after it the one starting at the lamp right of S, eg. D and E, we can see than some lamps are flipped two times (ie. stay unchanged) and only the first and last affected one are permanently changed:

```
ABCDEFGHIJ  
   XXXX      //this
    XXXX     //and this together

   X   X     //is the same as this alone
```

After both flip sequences, only D and H are different from before;
E,F,G are flipped two times = unchanged. So, using this pattern,
it's possible to change only two lamps with `k` distance (4 in this case),
instead of `k` lamps.
.

Now, using this pattern on A changes E too, and using it on E changes I. Using it on any other lamp than A,E,I won´t affect A,E,I. ... In other words, it´s possible to split all (10) lamps in k (4) groups:

```
A,E,I  
B,F,J  
C,G  
D,H
```

which are completely independent, ie. calculating the optimal solution for each group independly will give us the total optimal solution (as long as we remember to use the switch pattern above).
.

Within one group, let's take AEI, we could think of the same pattern with a smaller scale, ie. A affects E and E affects I (as said above), and the possible flip patterns are

```
ABCDE
xx
 xx
  xx
   xx
```

Maybe you see now that, with chaining these patterns, we can flip any two lamps in this group, even if they are not consecutive, as long as it's *two* lamps. Ie. AB or AC or AD or AE or BC etc.
Now, getting to the real data, if the number of switched-off lamps is even, you can switch on pairs like described above until all lamps are un, and then that group is finished. If the number was uneven, select the lamp with the lowest value as the only one that remains off.

Comment: However, here is a problem with **"select the lamp with the lowest value as the only one that remains off"**. It fails when init `string = "001000001"`, `a[] = { 1000, 3, 10, 8, 999, 7, 4, 6, 998, 10 }`. The `AEI` is `"000"` and value is `{ 1000, 999, 998 }`, since the number is 3 which is odd, so we should discard the lowest `998`, **but it is very large for others**. Obviously, in this case we can not discard the lowest one.

Comment: @loverszhaokai And that means you just found out that the solution from "mnbvmar" isn´t optimal :) (Actually, I didn´t think that far before :p)

Comment: Yes. I do not know why "mnbvmar" 's solution can get the right answer. Such as, `init string="00001"`, and `a[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 2 }` and `K = 4`, in "mnbvmar"'s solution, the first group is "01" and value is `{ 1, 2 }`, and we should discard the lowest one which is `1`, but obviously we can not discard it, the best way is to toggle the first 4 bits, and it will be all "11111".